# When did Darth Vader/Anakin really lose his right hand?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, luke-skywalker

I've seen the movies. I know that Dooku cut off Anakin's hand during Episode 2.  However, I'm in the process of reading *Dark Force Rising*, and in it, Mara Jade tells Luke Skywalker that Vader lost his right hand as a result of the Emperor's anger over losing the first Death Star.

So, which is it?  Clearly, I'd assume the book is in "error" here.  But, is there something more to this?

Comment: Movie canon > EU novel canon, I do believe

Comment: Yes.  Movies trump books.  Pretty much everything written about the Mandolorians was overturned by the Close Wars Series, for example.

Comment: Yeah, like all being from New Zealand... (cough cough)

Comment: It's not an "error", just a case of g-canon beats EU

Comment: I haven't read the books, but is it possible she was just going by hearsay and the information she received and passed on was simply incorrect?  Or does the book imply that she was actually there when it happened?

Comment: The answer given is pretty straight forward regarding the given sources in question. However, Splinter of the Minds Eye has Luke cutting off Vader's hand and was written pre-Prequel series and pre-Return of the Jedi, and allegedly Lucas had oversight on the script. Just an interesting foot note.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following quote appears in the book "[Heir to the Empire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heir_to_the_Empire)" by Timothy Zahn;

> "I don't imagine that the Emperor was pleased," Luke murmured. "No, he
>   wasn't," Mara said, her voice dark with memories of her own. "Vader
>   nearly died for that blunder." Deliberately, she looked over at Luke's
>   hands. **"That was when he lost his right hand, in fact."**

There is no further explanation given in the book, nor is the the quote consistent with G-Canon since he'd already lost his right hand in a fight with Dooku;

[image: Dooku Fight]

Comment: Yes, that is the passage I was referring to.

Comment: OK. This is simply a case of film canon just ignoring the books.

Comment: @Richard - the other way around. *Heir to the Empire* and *Dark Force Rising* came out years before episode II.

Comment: @neilfein - That's what I'm saying. Although it was covered in the book, George Lucas just plain ignored the book when he wrote the new film.

Comment: @Richard - Next time I'll actually read the comment before replying to it.

Comment: @neilfein - As long as you hate Jarjar we'll get along fine.

Comment: They could both be correct. He could have had his hand cut off twice. If it's a flesh and bone hand or circuits and actuators, it's irrelevant. It's still 'his hand'. He will get another...

Comment: @Morgan: I've seen that theory before, but to my knowledge it has yet to be retconned into existence, despite being widely-accepted amongst fans. Give it time, I'm sure someone, maybe even Zahn himself, will incorporate that into a book soon.

Comment: I would say that Lucas had the whole Anakin-losing-hand-to-Dooku thing in his mind for a while, but just didn't bother to contradict Zahn's version when he wrote it.  To retcon the whole thing, artificial hands appear capable of sensation; the emperor cutting it off (again) would mean that Vader would be out of action for less time, as only the new hand would need to be attached, not requiring the whole issue of healing the stump first.  Mara might not have known that - she may simply have seen Vader go to speak to the Emperor and come back less a hand.

Comment: @MontyWild - More likely Lucas couldn't give a crap what's in the EU books. He's made it pretty clear that he doesn't read them and isn't bound by them.

Comment: @Richard, my point exactly, though I think that Lucas *did* give just a *small* crap about the EU novels - in that they kept the franchise in peoples' minds, and hence increased his profits...  He just didn't let them influence *his* story.  Lucas has shown himself to be all for anything that promotes profits, from fanflicks to novels, to advertising that the consumer must pay for (Starwars.com's "Hyperspace").